# how to know if segue was push or modal

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

Say I segue from UIViewController A to UIViewController B. Is there a way to know, from inside UIViewController B, whether UIViewController B was a result of a push vs a modal segue?

Comment: Note, the accepted answer in the duplicate is not the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your view controller has its property `presentingViewController` set to something other than `nil`, then it's being presented modally by that controller. Else, you can assume it's been pushed (thus, `self.parentViewController` should be an `UINavigationController`).